# Strange Minecraft LAN connection issue

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have an odd issue with Minecraft Java Edition.
I have two computers in the house that I want to play a LAN game on.

- Both are connected to the same network
- Both have network discovery and file sharing turned on
- Both can access each other's public folders via Windows Explorer
- Both are running Windows 10
- All Javaw.exe are allowed through Windows Firewall

So if I start a new world and 'Open to LAN' on 'Machine 1', the other can find it on the Multiplayer screen but fails to connect

> io.netty.channel.abstractchannel$annotatedconnectexception

It also won't connect via 'Direct Connect'

If I start a new world and 'Open to LAN' on 'Machine 2', it fails to appear on the Multiplayer server screen on 'Machine 1', but I can 'Direct Connect' to it using IP/Port and it will open fine.

So obviously they can talk to other, but only in a limited capacity.
Has anybody else had this issue or could suggest a possible cause?

Comment: Please don't ask "has anyone else had this issue" unless you mean "has anyone been through this and has fixed it," there's a lot of that on StackExchange. Also, you might want to try asking this on another StackExchange site, like Super User or possibly Stack Overflow itself. Don't just copy & paste, though, because some people might not like that. Instead, you could word it differently to focus more on the interaction between the two PCs.

Comment: Sorry. I thought I was being polite and not demanding answers to problems. I will ask around as you suggest.

Comment: Oh no its fine, you are being polite. I was just letting you know since you're a new contributer/asker on here. I suggest going through [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) Meta FAQ if you want to write better & clearer questions.